# Awk calculation rounding output to integers

Tags: awk

I have a calculation and I need it's output as a whole number, but it might return one with decimals.

```
    echo $((ram/50)) | awk '{printf( "%.0f\n", $1*0.$1 )}'
```

So, the ram/50, in this case, returns 36, that is piped to awk. I want awk to multiply the number by 0.the number itself, so: 36*0.36. This would return 12.96, that I want to be rounded to 13. As the command is now, the 36*0.36 calculation doesn't work and printf only removes the .96, it doesn't round it off.

Comment: You need to specify your flavor of awk. Different flavors could vary in significant ways. I tried both OS X system awk and gawk, and got 13 in both cases.

Comment: Returns 36 on `GNU Awk 3.1.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to operator precedence. Multiplication is higher precedence than string concatenation, so you need some parentheses in order to make it work as you expect:

```
echo 36 | awk '{ printf "%.0f\n", $1 * ("0." $1) }'
```

In your version, the order of operations means that you're multiplying field 1 by 0, then concatenating with field 1, before passing the result to `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
echo $((ram/50)) | awk '{ v=$1*$1/100; print (v==int(v) ? v : int(v)+1) }'
```

Actual calculation happens in `v=$1*$1/100`. Then while printing, round off to next integer if required.

Comment: I think they want it rounding to the nearest integer not always up, as that is the behaviour of the printf command they were using.You could achieve it by using `print int(v+0.5)`